# How do I configure my jupyter notebook so that it uses the available GPU while working with keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, jupyter-notebook, gpu-shared-memory

I searched for solutions and installed tensorflow-gpu with pip.

```
tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')
```

This code returns an empty list. `[]`

[You can see I have 2 GPUs but none of them are being used when I am doing image processing(CNN) with keras.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rPNBV.png)

I am new to things so don't understand exactly what is wrong. Please help me configure so that I can use my GPU for processing. I am working with Windows 10 64-bit, Python-3.8.7.
As suggested, I tried importing tensorflow on python terminal, and got the following error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
```

> 2021-02-13 22:52:17.253841: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:52:17.266384: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.

Followed by this when I tried listing the GPUs:
`tf.config.list_physical_devices('GPU')`

> 2021-02-13 22:57:17.390319: I tensorflow/compiler/jit/xla_cpu_device.cc:41] Not creating XLA devices, tf_xla_enable_xla_devices not set
> 2021-02-13 22:57:17.749790: I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library nvcuda.dll
> 2021-02-13 22:57:18.937838: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1720] Found device 0 with properties:
> pciBusID: 0000:01:00.0 name: **GeForce MX150** computeCapability: 6.1
> coreClock: 1.5315GHz coreCount: 3 deviceMemorySize: 2.00GiB deviceMemoryBandwidth: 44.76GiB/s
> 2021-02-13 22:57:18.966071: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:18.974209: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublas64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublas64_11.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:18.981154: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cublasLt64_11.dll'; dlerror: cublasLt64_11.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:18.988826: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cufft64_10.dll'; dlerror: cufft64_10.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:18.996411: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'curand64_10.dll'; dlerror: curand64_10.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:19.002563: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusolver64_10.dll'; dlerror: cusolver64_10.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:19.009636: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cusparse64_11.dll'; dlerror: cusparse64_11.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:19.018025: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:60] Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found
> 2021-02-13 22:57:19.025064: W tensorflow/core/common_runtime/gpu/gpu_device.cc:1757] Cannot dlopen some GPU libraries. Please make sure the missing libraries mentioned above are installed properly if you would like to use GPU. Follow the guide at https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu for how to download and setup the required libraries for your platform.
> Skipping registering GPU devices...
> []

Comment: Have you installed CUDA Toolkit and cuDNN ? There are countless tutorials for that on the internet...

Comment: will try, thankyou!

Comment: Run your code in a python shell (not in jupyter) and  you will see a log that tells you everything on why the GPU is not detected. You could include it in your question (as text, not as image).

Comment: If you import `tf` on terminal, you should see `I tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:49] Successfully opened dynamic library cudart64_110.dll` otherwise there something wrong in your set up.

Comment: I got an error message while importing tf on python terminal, mentioned it in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_110.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_110.dll not found` This error message says Tensorflow-gpu requires CUDA 11

`Could not load dynamic library 'cudnn64_8.dll'; dlerror: cudnn64_8.dll not found` This error message says cuDNN 8 is required to run Tensorflow-gpu version.

Install right version `CUDA` and `cuDNN` and follow the instructions mentioned [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu#windows_setup) to setup GPU support on Windows OS.

Comment: I get this list now:
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]

Thanks!! :)